# Amazon sagemaker Lifecycle configuration not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, pytorch, amazon-sagemaker, torchtext

I have the following Lifecycle configuration file in Amazon sagemaker

```bash
#!/bin/bash
sudo -u ec2-user -i <<'EOF'

source activate conda_pytorch_p36

# Replace myPackage with the name of the package you want to install.
conda install -c pytorch torchtext
# You can also perform "conda install" here as well.

source deactivate

EOF
```

But when I try to import torchtext on a jupyter notebook inside the pytorch_conda_p36 virtual environment I get a module not found error

This is my code

```python
from sagemaker import get_execution_role

role = get_execution_role()
bucket='sagemaker-us-east-2-964130302244'
data_dir = 'dataset'
data_location = 's3://{}/{}'.format(bucket, data_dir)

import torch
import torch.utils.data as tud
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.nn.functional as F
from collections import Counter, defaultdict
import operator
import os, math
import numpy as np
import random
import copy
import s3fs
import torchtext
fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem()
```

The error I get is the following

```python
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-c9a96a48b0b7> in <module>
     11 import copy
     12 import s3fs
---> 13 import torchtext
     14 fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem()
     15 # from nltk import word_tokenize

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torchtext'
```

Comment: Please add the error you got to help others answer you question. Thanks.